# Realm: predicate returning LazyFilterCollection - how to convert to Results<T>?

Tags: swift, realm, nspredicate

I'm filtering my database query with `NSPredicate`s directly on the database, but then I would like to go further and filter the returned values (`Results<T>`) with a custom predicate:

```
elements.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    return ... 
}
```

this one returns a `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection` - how can I use this and get the Results again?

Answer (score 2):

We're tracking adding support for block-based predicates in [GitHub issue #2138](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2138). This will allow you to perform custom filtering outside of that supported via Realm's built-in primitives.

If you need to sometimes work with a `Results<T>` and other times work with a `LazyFilterBidirectionalCollection` you can wrap the values in a type-erased wrapper such as `AnyBidirectionalCollection<T>`, which forwards any operations to the wrapped type, while hiding the underlying collection.

For instance:

```
func maybeFilter(results: Results<Foo>) -> AnyBidirectionalCollection<Foo> {
    if (condition) {
        return AnyBidirectionalCollection(results.filter { $0.foo != "bar" })
    }
    return AnyBidirectionalCollection(results)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Does this mean it's currently not possible what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: That's correct. I don't expect it will ever be possible to create a `Results<T>` from an arbitrary sequence since `Results<T>` is inherently a live-updating view into a Realm, and there's no way to live-update without Realm knowing how to reapply any filtering that has occurred.

Comment: Ok, so the best option for me would me converting it to a Swift array and filter that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the resulting collection? If you don't care about the specific concrete type of the collection you could just work with the `LazyFilteredBidirectionalCollection` that `Results.filter(_:)` returns.

Comment: last question: how can I return both from a method? I.e. I currently return `Results<MyModel>` and would like to sometimes filter it with a custom predicate as well, so I need something to handle both, `Results<MyModel>` as well as the resulting `LazyFilteredBidrectionalCollection`... can you give me a hint?

Comment: You can declare the return type as something like `AnyBidirectionalCollection<MyModel>`, which can wrap any bidirectional collection type.

Comment: I already tried that, unfortunately I get `Cannot convert return expression of type 'Results<MyModel>' to return type 'AnyBidirectionalCollection<MyModel>'`

Comment: You need to initialize a `AnyBidirectionalCollection<T>` from the `Results<T>` (`return AnyBidirectionalCollection(myResults)`).